# How to add react-phone-number-input to -react-final-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm currently creating a form using `react-final-form` and trying to use `react-phone-number-input` with it through integration as an adapter, as displayed through [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/40mr0v2r87).

I attempted to use the example to learn how it is done, but I'm not sure how to access the component and create the adapter for it properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input';

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const onSubmit = async values => {
  await sleep(300)
  window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2))
}

const PhoneAdapter = ({ input, meta, ...rest }) => (
    <PhoneInput
    {...input}
    {...rest}
    value={input.value}
    onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(value)}
  />
  )

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <Form
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              initialValues={{ }}
              render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <fieldset>
                  <Field component={PhoneAdapter} />
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <button type="submit" disabled={submitting || pristine}>
                      Submit
                    </button>
                  </fieldset>
                  <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
                </form>
              )}
            />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: July 2019

Apparently, all you need to do is to spread the input property of Field. Works flawlessly. Learn about spreading if you're not familiar with it.

```
const PhoneAdapter = ({ input }) => (
    <PhoneInput {...input} />
)

<Field name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" component={PhoneAdapter} />
```

---

I ended up experimenting with the FieldRenderProps props until it worked out. I wasn't so sure whether it would work or not, as `react-phone-number-input` is two elements in a component. I thought it would implement the input on only one of the elements.

By using `input`, I gain access to the input's props. Hence, I called upon it's value, as the default looks like so:

```
<PhoneInput
  placeholder="Enter phone number"
  value={ this.state.value } // This is what I called.
  onChange={ value => this.setState({ value }) }/>
```

I then did the same for the onChange function prop.

```
const PhoneAdapter = ({ input }) => (
    <PhoneInput value={input.value.value} onChange={value => input.onChange(value)} />
)
```

Finally, I used the component adapter like so:

```
<Field name="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number" component={PhoneAdapter} />
```